# creating a filter for second factor of authentication

Tags: java, jsp, iis, tomcat, servlets

I have a two factor based authentication server which i need to integrate to a existing web application

**Existing application description:-**

java JSP, servlet application

running on tomcat server 6.0

source code is not available

**My twofactor solution provide following integrations:-**

1. web service which receive username and OTP returns "true " or "false"
2. Has a OTP page which can be called from any website sending username,targetPage as parameter (credit card transaction type)

**Problem statement**

I need to integrate my two-factor(OTP verification ) to the existing application ,so that OTP is asked on every login and user has no way he can enter the application without OTP .
I have heard about creating filters on the web server(of exiting application ) but It will allow intruder to use his OTP and the victim's password

- I cannot make changes to the existing application
- I have complete control on my two-factor application . ( i can modify and create more API's)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Tomcat valve which intercepts all requests and prompts for the OTP. This way if the user does not enter a valid OTP the request won't even make it to the webapp

Comment: can you please elaborate or suggest some article if possible

Comment: Take a look at the tomcat [AuthenticatorBase](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/AuthenticatorBase.html) class (a valve). You may also want to take a look at our Cloudseal [authenticator valve](https://github.com/cloudseal/tomcat-valve). It plugs into our single sign on platform (which supports two factor authentication)